# How to remove the intersecting mask between lines to avoid large polygons?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to find minimum area rectangles from a mask image. I'm using the below code

```
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for c in contours:
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    box = np.int0(cv2.boxPoints(rect))
    cv2.polylines(img,[box.reshape((-1,1,2))],True,(0,255,0),4)
```

The output looks like the second image and the expected output is 3rd image:

[image]
[image]
[image]

My problem is the large boxes provided by minAreaRect because of small intersecting mask between above and below lines as highlighted above in the output image. Any ideas on how to handle this?

Comment: Please show the expected output. Even if it is obvious to you, it is not to me.

Comment: try to use ```cv2.erode``` function

Comment: You need to clean up your image before thresholding to get the mask. Please show your original input image before making the mask and your code to create the mask.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Added the expected output.

Comment: What about the one in the bottom, which is the most problematic ?

Comment: The one I have highlighted has a bigger impact. @YvesDaoust

Comment: Mh, that does not answer my question.